# How do I get my input data in a fixed box size? C++

Tags: c++

How do I keep all of my data in a fixed box? I want the numbers to keep the box size the same and fill out right to left as it gets largers. My current code, has it | on each side of the box move.

I'll provide my current output, code and desired outputs.

Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c = ' ';
    string s = "";

    while (c != 'E')
    {
        //c = _getch();
        c = getchar(); // 1 enter 2 enter
        if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == ' ') continue;
        cout << "Character is=" << c << endl;
        s = s + c;
        cout << "+------------+" << endl;
        cout << "|          "  << s << "|"<< endl;
        cout << "+------------+" << endl;
        cout << "string being built is:" << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Current Output:

```
+------------+
|          123123|
+------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+------------+
|      123123|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should be using `cin >> c` to read the user's input, rather than using `getchar()`. `operator>>` will ignore whitespace characters in the input for you.

Second, you are writing out the same number of whitespace characters in front of `s` regardless of its length.  You need to reduce the number of whitespace characters written out each time `s` grows in length, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    string s, ws = "            ";

    while (cin >> c && c != 'E')
    {
        cout << "Character is=" << c << endl;
        s += c;
        if (!ws.empty()) ws.pop_back();
        cout << "+------------+" << endl;
        cout << "|" << ws << s << "|"<< endl;
        cout << "+------------+" << endl;
        cout << "string being built is:" << s << endl;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/vdgqGc)

A better option is to instead use the [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) I/O stream manipulator (you are already aware of `<iomanip>`, but you are not using any manipulators in your code). Let the stream handle the spacing, you don't need to manage it manually, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    string s;

    while (cin >> c && c != 'E')
    {
        cout << "Character is=" << c << endl;
        s += c;
        cout << "+------------+" << endl;
        cout << '|' << setw(12) << s << '|' << endl;
        cout << "+------------+" << endl;
        cout << "string being built is:" << s << endl;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/s5rryT)

Alternatively, also look at the [`std::setfill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) and [`std::right`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) I/O stream manipulators, which you can use to help you write out your box edges too (the default fill is `' '` and the default fill adjustment is `right`, which is why they are not needed in the example above), eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
     
int main()
{
    char c;
    string s;

    while (cin >> c && c != 'E')
    {
        cout << "Character is=" << c << endl;
        s += c;
        cout << '+' << setw(13) << setfill('-') << '+' << endl;
        cout << '|' << setw(12) << setfill(' ') << s << '|' << endl;
        cout << '+' << setw(13) << setfill('-') << '+' << endl;
        cout << "string being built is:" << s << endl;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/d7vE5Y)